# How is the variable of union accessing the members?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

union p
{
    int x;
    char y;
} k = {1, 97};

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", k.y);
}
```

The answer is 1 and I don't understand how. Can anyone please explain?

Comment: Does this really compile? Most probably your compile generates a warning and drops the second initializer (97).

Comment: You do know that the members of a union *share* the memory? Modifying a single member, could (depending on type-size and byte-order) change *all* members.

Comment: Perhaps the keyword you're looking for is `struct`.

Comment: MSVC says "error C2078: too many initializers." That is because there is only one member.

Comment: @WeatherVane: There are quite clearly two members in the union. The reason there should be only one initializer is C 2018 6.7.9 17: “When no designations are present, subobjects of the current object are initialized in order according to the type of the current object: … the first named member of a union.”

Answer (score 3):

The first member of the initializer is put into the first named member of the union, therefore changing the value of all members, as all members of the union share the same memory. Then, reading from `y` reads from the value stored in the union, or `1`.

The second member of the initializer is ignored in practice, but should issue a compiler diagnostic for compliant compilers.

For GCC, this diagnostic should look roughly like this:

```
test.c:7:11: warning: excess elements in union initializer
 } k = {1, 97};
           ^~
test.c:7:11: note: (near initialization for ‘k’)
```